# gVim not colouring array of strings properly

Tags: vim

I have got this large list of names here http://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt, which I am keeping in a (python) list for sorting.

What is wrong with gVim, why is it not colouring the strings properly? Also if I change the name of list, the colouring shifts. Like deleting 2 characters, makes **"S** highlight as well.

[image]

How can I fix it?

**EDIT-** I also note that gVim is acting sluggishly for a mere 14 lines of code (including this line, 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be the `'synmaxcol'` setting, which limits the columns to search for syntax items (default is 3000 characters). If you want to trade speed for correctness, turn this off via

```
:set synmaxcol=0
```

Comment: It does seem to solve the long line highlight, however my old x200 laptop chokes like 10 seconds just for jumping to the end of that line (-:

Comment: That solves the problem! But gVim becomes so slow. Ha, I have set this in my vimrc `set synmaxcol=1000`.

Comment: Yes, syntax highlighting can bog down Vim in pathological / extreme cases. Sometimes it's due to the way the syntax is defined (you could send feedback to the syntax plugin author), but sometimes this is just due to Vim's general regexp engine (there's an optimization that hopefully will be included one day).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your input line is just too long for the syntax highlighter to pick up entirely,  vim supports various options to define how many lines or characters the syntax highlighter should look back to get the syntax state.

For maximum correctness (and slowness) use: `:syntax sync fromstart`
For performance, try these:

```
set nocursorcolumn
set nocursorline
syntax sync minlines=256
```

See the [:help syn-sync](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3asyn-sync) page for reference, and check out [this wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_syntax_highlighting).

Comment: I added `syntax sync fromstart` to the first line of my vimrc. Reopening the file, makes no difference. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: `.vimrc` is parsed once when vim starts (if reopen means open/close) than it probably not the solution. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11937012/1515540) applies here too